# How can I take first 4 letter of a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
time
201201
201110
.
.
.
```

and I wish to take first four letters of the column.
(answer would look like 2012, 2011...)
How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Same as with any other sequence or iterable:

```
[ value[:4] for value in df["time"] ]
```

Depending on what you want to do with it you could use `apply()` etc., but as far as your question goes I don't see any reason to.